# Off taste of over-boiled soup, what is the chemistry?

Tags: food-chemistry, taste

I had a tin of Asian soup where the label explicitly states "don't boil". It happens, it did boil, and afterwards had a taste that reminded me clearly of the smell I remember from stale soap water, such as from washing clothes without a washing machine.

What is it that caused that? Asking for the substances as well as how they are produced.

Comment: Telling us what the listed ingredients on the back of the can were might help.

Comment: @ClangorousChimera This is the first time that I regret not having empty tin can as a fetish. The can has been discarded long ago ant this soup is not continuously marketed, so I have to relay on my memory: main ingredient were glass  noodles, with some chicken meat, enriched with east Asian spices. But i did have the same taste with other soups too.

Comment: Hmmm well I'm not really sure what it could be. Perhaps you should start of a fetish of having empty Asian soup tin cans until you find that kind that you encounter the soapiness with. This does seam like a puzzling situation.